# Uncaught TypeError: playlist1.toHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

**Hello everyone !**
I really need your help on this because I can't figure out why it doesn't work.
The error as I wrote is :

> Uncaught TypeError: playlist1.toHTML is not a function

JS :

```
function test(){
    var playlist1 = new Playlist();
    var music1 = new Music('theurl');
    var music2 = new Music('anotherUrl');
    var container = document.getElementById('results');
    container.innerHTML = playlist1.toHTML();
}
var id=0;
function Music(url){
    this.id=id+1;
    this.url=url;
    this.name="unknown";
    this.author="unknown";
    this.album="unknown";
    this.cover="unknown";
}
var nb=0;
function Playlist(){
    nb=nb+1;
    this.elements = [];
    this.nom = 'playlist'+nb;
}
function toHTML(){
    var text="";
    for(var i=0; i<this.elements.length; i++){
        text+= "<li>\n";
        text+= "<div>\n";
        text+= "<figure class='music' track='"+this.elements[i].getUrl()+"'></figure>";
        text+= "<img src='"+this.elements[i].getCover()+"'>\n";
        text+= "</div>\n";
        text+= "<div>\n";
        text+= "<h3>"+this.elements[i].getName()+"</H3>\n";
        text+= "<h4>"+this.elements[i].getAuthor()+" - "+this.elements[i].getAlbum()+"</H4>\n";
        text+= "</div>\n";
        text+= "</li>\n";
    }
    return text;
}
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="arrays.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="test()">Make it</button>
        <p id="results"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd be really please if someone could help me solve this problem :)

Comment: `this.toHTML = toHTML` in your Playlist definition maybe?

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to help me but I don't think I understood your comment ? - IrkenInvader

Comment: `function Playlist(){
    nb=nb+1;
    this.elements = [];
    this.nom = 'playlist'+nb;
    this.toHTML = toHTML;
}`

Comment: I'll post an answer and remove it if that doesn't solve it for you

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I'll try what you just wrote

Comment: don't remove the parenthesis from the `playlist1.toHTML()` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class method is not defined like yours. It should be written inside the definition of the **`prototype`** of that new class.

```
var SomeObject = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
}

SomeObject.prototype = {
    Output: function(dom) {
        dom.innerHTML += this.data + "<br/>";
    }
}

var a = new SomeObject("value");
a.Output(document.querySelector("#log"));
```

Take a look at how [Mozilla Developer Network teaches OO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and you'll be better coding OO in JS, perhaps. =)

Comment: Sorry I'm not used to javascript.. I'll check your link to figure out how it works then Thanks !

Comment: Of course I tested my getters and the problems don't come from those

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `toHTML` on a playlist, but you have not defined that function on the playlist object.

So in order to use `container.innerHTML = playlist1.toHTML();`

You need to make that function part of the playlist object.

```
function Playlist(){
    nb=nb+1;
    this.elements = [];
    this.nom = 'playlist'+nb;
    this.toHTML = toHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I'll change that !